# NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() keeps returning false on emulator

Tags: uwp, windows-phone, connectivity

I have been working on an UWP app for some time now and have always used a call to

```
NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

to check if there was a network connection.
Yesterday I decided to format my computer and do a fresh install of Windows and all dev tools etc. I got everything working pretty quickly and checked the internet connection with other apps on the emulator. 
But every time I check if a network is available it returns false, so my app won't work how it is supposed to anymore. I really don't understand why it returns false when the internet connection works in all of the other apps.
Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in the Emulator, see: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/08d2f8c9-828e-4b06-a5c8-9283694dd792/uwpc-i-got-issues-when-checking-connect-to-internet-on-emulator-universal-app-please-help-me?forum=wpdevelop 

Personally, I solved it by using `#if DEBUG` to always return true (=internet available) and only use the mentioned method in release mode.

Comment: @sibbl Oh, well, I'll just use the same directive until the bug is resolved. Thank you for the quick answer!